# shorter way to write if(x==1 || x==5 || x==7 || x==22)

Tags: php, javascript

Programming in JavaScript and PHP, is there a shorter way to include several options in an if() condition?

I wonder if there is a way to write see a way to write for example

```
if( myvar==1 || myvar==5 || myvar==7 || myvar==22 )
```

something like

```
if( myvar==(1||5||7||22) )
```

Anyone knows a way to do this? Maybe regex?

Comment: check http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php function for php!

Comment: dont know PHP - but from JS perspective -Make an array of 1 5 7 22 .. Use indexOf() of operation thereafter

Comment: Note that while the implementations between JavaScript and PHP will be different, the idea is the same: stick your possible values in an array and check if your variable is in there.

Comment: I wonder why this was downvoted!

Comment: And I wonder why it was "closed as not constructive".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For javascript you can add all on a array and you can check that myvar is present in array or not by .indexOf

```
if([1,5,7,22].indexOf(myvar)!=-1){
//do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use array to keep all values

```
$os = array(1, 3, 5, 22);
if (in_array(x, $os))  
{  
   ///...  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As Venu mentioned.

```
<?php

    $array = array(1, 5, 7, 22);
    if (in_array($myvar, $array))
    {
        // my var is either 1, 5, 7 or 22
    }

?>
```